# Correct or incorrect use of the word “Criminalistic”?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering whether “criminalistic” is the correct word to use in this sentence:

“Even though many believe he was a villain for being an apparent corrupt criminalistic politician, Augustus, formally known as Octavian ...”

I have done multiple searches but I don't  really understand what they are saying. Here is the website I was looking at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/criminalistic .If it’s not the right word can you please suggest some alternatives?

What I'm basically trying to say is that people have said he was a “corrupt politician” and “rose to power by criminal methods”, but when I type criminalistic into word it tries to change it to “criminalistics” and obviously that’s not the right word to use.

Comment: What's the difference between corrupt and criminalistic?  "Rose to power by criminal means" seems to me different from performing public duties in a corrupt manner. "Inclined toward criminality" may be more suggestive of these differences.

Comment: I know someone whose native language is Russian, who tends to use (and make up) words like "criminalistic" in place of the simpler English usage of "criminal"--a noun also used as an adjective.

Comment: I would interpret "criminalistic", in most contexts, to mean "behaving like a criminal".

Answer (score 1):

According to *Merriam-Webster* online **criminalistics** means

> [The] application of scientific techniques in collecting and analyzing physical evidence in criminal cases

And in the UK it's called **forensics**. Whereas **criminalistic** means

> tending to criminality

So your Word grammar/spell checker is not being helpful as *criminalistic* is a word in its own right.

It might be clearer to say in your sentence what you said in attempting to clarify what you're asking. Something like this perhaps:

> ...many believe he was a villain because he was a *corrupt politician who rose to power through criminal methods*...

(I've left out "apparent" because I'm not sure it's necessary, or maybe another word might be better if you are saying that he was clearly corrupt and/or clearly used criminal methods.)

Answer (score 0):

Either *it is apparent that he is* or *he is apparently*.

Either way, *criminalistic* instead of *criminal* is a stretch too far.

There are circumstances in which *an apparent… politician* might be acceptable and this isn’t one.

Answer (score 0):

> “Even though many believe he was a politician known for his
>   **felonious** talents, Augustus, formally known as Octavian ... "

[oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/felonious)

> **felonious**
>
> ```
> Relating to or involved in crime.
> ‘They turned their felonious talents to the smuggling trade’
> ```
>
> illegal, illicit, lawbreaking, illegitimate, against the law